# Qt: the signal handler is not called when the signal is emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qt-signals

I am doing something like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(QWidget *parent) : QLabel(parent)
{
    this->MyMenu = new QMenu();

    QAction* act_del = new QAction(MyMenu);
    act_delete->setText("MyAction");

    MyMenu->addAction(act_del);

    QObject::connect(act_del,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(MySlot()));
}

void MyClass::MySlot()
{
    //Not called
}
```

Any suggestion on when the SIGNAL is triggered the SLOT is not called. Here is where the menu is displayed:

```
void MyClass::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *ev)
{
    QPoint globalPos = this->mapToGlobal(ev->pos());

    QAction* selectedItem = MyMenu->exec(globalPos);
    if (selectedItem)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        // nothing was chosen
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on why the SLOT is not called?

Comment: Do you get some errors in application output related to that? Does _MyClass_ contain the Q_OBJECT macro?

Comment: Also, QObject::connect returns boolean - it worth to check if it returns true

Comment: We need to see at least the signal and slot definitions for MyClass, as well as the actual connect call. You've probably got a mis-match somewhere in there (hence the previous comment to check the return value of the connect).

Comment: @Zlatomir yes it was missing the macro. I thought that would be inherited. Could you put that down as the answer. I was missing the macro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*MyClass* needs to contain the [Q_OBJECT](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example) macro for the signal-slot connections to work.